# Trying to read a text file, Encrypt it with XOR, then Write it to a new text file

Tags: c++, encryption, bit-manipulation, xor

I am trying to design a program that will open any text file, read it into a string, encrypt the string with XOR, and write the string to a new text file. The code below works, but generates multiple "system beeps".

My wild guess is that I am not handling whitespaces correctly? I'm not sure. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    // Define variables
    string fileName,
        key = "seacrest out";

    // Input
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file you wish to encrypt: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;

    inFile.open(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary);
    string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>()); // Reads a text file into a single string.
    inFile.close();
    cout << "The file has been read into memory as follows:" << endl;   
    cout << str << endl;
    system("pause");

    // Encryption
    cout << "The file has been encrypted as follows:" << endl;
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < str.size(); x++)           // Steps through the characters of the string.
        str[x] ^= key[x % key.size()];                  // Cycles through a multi-character encryption key, and encrypts the character using an XOR bitwise encryption.
    cout << str << endl;                                // This code works, but I get system beeps. Something is still wrong.

    // Write Encrypted File
    cout << "Please enter the file name to save the encrypted file under: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;

    outFile.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);
    outFile.write(str.c_str(), str.size());         // Writes the string to the binary file by first converting it to a C-String using the .c_str member function.

    system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: in order to avoid this problem you could encode the xor values e.g. writing the hex value as a string 0x07 -> "07"

Answer (score 2):

those beep sounds you heard are bytes equal to 0x07 in your file. you can get rid of this problem simply by not printing the contents of a binary file in the console.

Answer (score 2):

kudos for trying to do it yourself.
the problem is you are not handling some characters carefully for eg white spaces may try to print out

> char d=(char)(7);
>
> printf("%c\n",d);

which is called a bell character.
here is an easy implementation for XOR encryption but i recommend to write your own version

http://programmingconsole.blogspot.in/2013/10/xor-encryption-for-alphabets.html

Answer (score 1):

When you xor bytes with some random key, you're going to get some unusual byte sequences. These byte sequences happen to correspond to some unprintable characters that you can use to make the console beep by sending them to the console.

If you remove the line

```
cout << str << endl;
```

You'll find that your console won't beep any more since you're not printing the erroneous byte sequences that the console is interpreting as commands to beep.

If your console is set to ASCII mode (which I assume it is since you have `system("PAUSE")` which indicates you're on Windows where the console is not Unicode unless you set it explicitly IIRC) then those unprintable characters are all bytes less than 0x1F and the byte 0x7F, and the character that causes the console to beep is 0x7 (called "bell").

### **tl;dr**

You get some 0x7 bytes in your encrypted data that cause the console to beep when printed. Remove `cout << str << endl;` to fix it.